# Getting InvalidOperationException when trying to inject db context into custom middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to inject a db context object into a custom middleware called *AuthenticateClient*, but I get the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'LC.Tools.API.Data.ApiDbContext' from root provider.

**AuthenticateClient.cs**:

```
public class AuthenticateClient
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly GenericUnitOfWork _worker;

    public AuthenticateClient(RequestDelegate next, ApiDbContext db, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<Utility.LCLog.Settings> settings)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(settings.Value.ApplicationName);
        _worker = new GenericUnitOfWork(new AppHelper(httpContext, db, env));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("key") || !context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("pass"))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Key or Pass missing from request header values");

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Client client;
            string key, pass;

            key = context.Request.Headers["key"];
            pass = context.Request.Headers["pass"];

            client = await _worker.GetRepo<Client>().SingleOrDefault(clnt => clnt.Active && clnt.Key.Equals(key) && clnt.Password.Equals(pass));

            if (client == null)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Client authentication failed", new string[] { "Key: " + key, "Password: " + pass, "Host: " + context.Request.Host });

                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Authentication failed");

                return;
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

**AuthenticateClientExtension.cs**:

```
public static class AuthenticateClientExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseClientAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticateClient>();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.ConnectionString));

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<Settings> lclog)
{
    loggerFactory.AddLCLog(lclog.Value);

    app.UseClientAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

**ApiDbContext.cs**:

```
public class ApiDbContext : DbContext, IApiDbContext
{
    public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `ApiDbContext` class look like?  Does it have dependencies?

Comment: the questions is updated with the ApiDbContext class

Comment: What is `AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer`? Does your app function without it?

Comment: I don't know how to set up the db context in any other way

Comment: I've changed the way I register the ApiDbContext, but still with same error

Answer (score 2):

> The solution was to use *IApplicationBuilder* to create scope and init
>   *ApiDbContext* and pass it to the middleware object. I also changed how I register the *ApiDbContext*

**AuthenticateClientExtension.cs**:

```
public static class AuthenticateClientExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseClientAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var scope = builder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
        ApiDbContext db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiDbContext>();

        return builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticateClient>(db);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.ConnectionString));

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<Settings> lclog)
{
    ...

    app.UseClientAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```